# delegate is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift-protocols

I created a pod library [in here](https://github.com/theduman/TDDropdownList)

Library contains a protocol. When I install library from cocoapods and try to conform the protocol I got `delegate is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level` error.

The protocol:

`@objc public protocol TDDropdownListDelegate {
    func listTapped(sender: UIButton)
}`

The protocol function:

```
open func listTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    activate(sender: sender)
    delegate?.listTapped(sender: sender)
}
```

The code I got the error

```
import UIKit
import TDDropdownList

class ViewController: UIViewController,TDDropdownListDelegate {
let a = TDDropdownList(frame: CGRect(x: 100 , y: 100 , width: 200 , height: 75))
override func viewDidLoad() {
    a.initialize(data: ["Emre","Duman"])

    a.delegate = self  // LINE I GOT THE ERROR

    self.view.addSubview(a)
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
func listTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    print(sender.currentTitle!)
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```